# Function inside route group [laravel-passport]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware, laravel-6

i have some function that check something and give back in some cases "exit();". 
i want to use it inside Route::group. 
how can i do it right without it impact all the other routes? thanks!

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
    myFunction (); //this function can give back: exit();
    Route::get('/test', 'Api\Test@test');
});
```

Comment: can you explain what do you want to do in those "some cases" and what are those "cases" exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn your function into middleware: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware

Group the routes that must be affected by your check, and leave out the routes that don't.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function() {
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['MyMiddleware']], function() {
      Route::get('/check-me', 'Api\Test@test1');
   });
   Route::get('/dont-check-me', 'Api\Test@test2');
});
```